# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable for time on Koalas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, spark-koalas

I am facing a small issue with a line of code that I am converting from pandas into Koalas.

Note: I am executing my code in the databricks.

The following line is pandas code:

```
input_data['t_avail'] = np.where(input_data['purchase_time'] != time(0, 0), 1, 0)
```

I did the conversion to Koalas as follows. Just to mention that I already have defined the input_data dataframe as Koalas type before the following line of code.

```
# Add a new column called 't_avail' in input_data Koalas dataframe
        input_data = input_data.assign( 
           t_avail = (input_data['purchase_time'] != time(0, 0))
           )
```

I get the following error with the Koalas conversion: `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

I am not sure what is the issue with the `time` module as I just want to assign the t_avail column with entries from the purchase_time column with entries that have a not empty time.

May someone help me resolve the issue? I think I am missing something silly.

Thank you to all.

Comment: Are you import the time module into the code?

Comment: Yes I have the ```import time``` in my code

Comment: can you explain why you use time(0,0) in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`As you say you import time module in your code.`

**This is because you write time(0,0).
However, time is a module and you use it as a function**

You can use this

```py
 input_data = input_data.assign( 
           t_avail = ((input_data['purchase_time']).str.strip() != "")
           )
```

Comment: I want to check from time values which are not null or empty  in the input_data['purchase_time'] column. How can I use the time module to check that? The entries in the ```purchase_time``` column are like ```03:26 PM``` etc.

Comment: May you help me modify the code to meet that check? I am not sure on how to do it

Comment: I get the error, ``` 'Series' object has no attribute 'strip'``. May you help resolve?

Comment: Sorry For that. I forget one thing

Comment: Now to check first and if this works then upvote. Also if you get errors just comment.

Comment: what is  the change you added?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241732/discussion-between-sharim-iqbal-and-laura-smith).